# Neural network programming; converting Matlab to C++

Tags: c++, matlab, neural-network, matlab-deployment

We have a program written in matlab software. It contains a [Hopfield net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfield_net) that saves a pattern after searching a large picture to find it.

Is it possible to rewrite this code in a programming language like c++, for increasing efficiency?

If it is possible, is it necessary to rewrite algorithms like the newhop learning algorithm again or are there already code examples to use?

Comment: Not 6, not 7 but 8 question marks! Is that a record????????

Comment: thanks a lot dear user. i dont simmilar with this site as you. you can help me whit a short comment

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a matlab to c++ button in matlab, so yes of course you can rewrite matlab stuff in c++.